# Creating reports with PHP - calculate tendency

Tags: php, mysql, report

I am trying to create a report from 4 different sets of data (all numbers from mysql queries). The report is a survey based on users' happiness with different aspects of their job, all from a rating of 1-10 (there are 11 questions in total) This is completed 4 times over the course of a year to get an idea of how things are going for them.

I can gather all of the data fine, but a tendency field is required. This tendency field will show if the users' have generally scored higher, lower or the same. I have managed to get something working for 2 of the 4 occurrences, but I have no idea how to work out properly for 4 occurrences.

So far I have this:

```
$trend = $var1 - $var2;
if ($trend > 0){ ?><img src="<?php echo base_url("assets/images/up.png")?>" /><?php }
elseif($trend == 0){ ?><img src="<?php echo base_url("assets/images/equal.png")?>" /><?php }
elseif($trend < 0){ ?><img src="<?php echo base_url("assets/images/down.png")?>" /><?php } ?>
```

I may be missing something out here, but I have been looking at this site for too long now so it'd be great to get some insight from someone else.

Any help would rock my world. Cheers.

Comment: Hello. What do you mean by occurrences? Are `$var1` and `$var2` occurrences? Where do these variables come from?

Comment: The occurrences are just different stages that the users' will take. The variables come from my controller, it is a number (from 1-10)